# PHP script to delete strong entity

Tags: php, ajax, database

(I can't post images, that needs at least 10 reptation)

I wanted to delete data in questionnaire table. 
I should post the ERD of my database but I can't post photo. so, here is the sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
    `accountID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `accountName` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pass` VARCHAR(20),
    `dob` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    `imagePath` VARCHAR(225) DEFAULT 'Assets/Profiles/default.jpg',
    `activated` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`)
);

CREATE TABLE questionnaire (
    questionnaireID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    accountID INT,
    questionnaireTitle VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'untitled',
    questionnaireDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    questionnaireExp DATE,
    answered INT,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (questionnaireID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (accountID)
        REFERENCES account (accountID)
);



 CREATE TABLE content (
        contentID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        questionnaireID INT,
        questionNumber INT,
        mediaDetailsID INT,
        question TEXT,
        required TINYINT DEFAULT '0',
        questionType INT,
        CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (contentID),
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (questionnaireID)
            REFERENCES questionnaire (questionnaireID),
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (mediaDetailsID)
            REFERENCES mediaDetails (mediaDetailsID)
    );

CREATE TABLE choices (
    choicesID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    choicesText TEXT,
    choicesValue INT,
    contentID INT,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (choicesID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (contentID)
        REFERENCES content (contentID)
);

CREATE TABLE mediaDetails (
    mediaDetailsID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    available TINYINT,
    mediaPath TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (mediaDetailsID)
);

CREATE TABLE answerEssay (
    answerEssayID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    aswerEssayDate TIMESTAMP,
    answer TEXT,
    contentID int,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (answerEssayID),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (contentID) REFERENCES content (contentID)
);
```

Using AJAX I called
`xhr.open("GET", "processing/questionnaire.php?do=load", false);`
**it was working fine, nothing errors.**

But when i called
 `xhr.open("GET", "processing/questionnaire.php?do=delete&id="+id, false);` 
it returned *Something went wrong, sorry.*

This is the questionnaire.php

```
include("includes/database.php");
if(isset($_GET["do"])){
    if($_GET["do"] == "load"){
        foreach ($account->question as $question)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"questID\" value=\"{$question->id}\"></td>";
            echo "<td>{$question->title}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$question->created}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$question->expired}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$question->ansewered}</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }else if($_GET["do"] == "delete"){
            /*
                questionType = 0  --> question type is text
                questionType = 1 --> checkbox
                questionType = 2 --> radio
             */             
           //delete choices data from table choices
            $query = "select * from content where questionnaireID={$_GET["id"]} and questionType in(1,2)";
            $result = execute($query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $query = "delete from choices where contentID={$row["contentID"]}";
                execute($query);
            }

        //delete answer for text question in answerEssay table
        $query = "select * from content where questionnaireID={$_GET["id"]} and questionType=0";
        $result = execute($query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $query = "delete from answerEssay where contentID={$row["contentID"]}";
            execute($query);
        }

        //delete all media details for each question in questionnaire
        $query = "select * from content where questionnaireID={$_GET["id"]}";
        $result = execute($query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $query = "delete from mediaDetails where mediaDetailsID={$row["mediaDetailsID"]}";
            execute($query);
        }

        //delete the questionnaire
        $query = "delete from questionnaire where questionnaireID={$_GET["id"]}";
        $result = execute($query);
        if($result){
            echo "Delete success!";
        }else{
            echo "Something went wrong, sorry.";
        }
    }
```

I think this is the best way to delete but it doesn't works...
Is there any alternative way to delete strong entity?
what's wrong in my code?

Comment: You can upload a photo somewhere else and put the link here..

Comment: add `or die(mysqli_error());` on every delete (`execute($query)`) to see whats going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Before you remove a questionnaire you should remove it's id first in the "content" table I guess. But i am not an expert.

So before calling DELETE FROM `questionnaire` call:

```
'UPDATE `content` SET questionnaireId = NULL where contentId = '.(int)$_GET['contentId'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error is. But I think the way you delete is not a good way...

You are trying to manually delete choices, answers and media details related to the questionnaire first. And then to delete the questionnaire. I don't think it's a good idea. In the schema you can define foreign key constraints like `ON DELETE CASCADE` to automatically delete the choices, answers and media details when you delete the questionnaire. Then you have to only delete the questionnaire. All other related entries will be deleted automatically.

Your delete operations are not atomic. As you do deletion in several steps, when multiple users try to execute queries, these queries may overlap resulting unexpected behavior with errors..

Also consider about the security of the queries you are using if you are going to use this in production. Your queries are vulnerable to sql injection attacks.